# Subtlety in converting doubles to a sound byte output

Tags: audio, byte, rounding, truncate, wave

I am looking to convert a double array with the range -1 to 1 to a byte output which will be saved in WAVE format. For the sake of argument, I'll concentrate on a simple 8 bit wave.

As far as I can see, there are two competing ways of doing this, both which offer very slightly different results, and the subtlety is quite complex.

---

**Method 1: output = (byte)(input * 128.0 + 128)**. In this case, a value of 1 is not permitted to be an input, otherwise, the illegal value 256 would be an output. Results are truncated to fit into a byte. Demonstration results:

- -1 --------> 0
- -0.5 ------> 64
- 0 ---------> 128
- 0.5 -------> 192
- 1-(1/128) -> 255
- 0.999999 --> 255 (equals 255.999872 truncated, legal)
- 1 ---------> 256 (illegal)

**Method 2: output = (byte)Round(input * 127.5 + 127.5)**. In this case, the value 1 **IS** allowed to be an input, with an output of 255 given. Unlike before, results are rounded. Demonstration results:

- -1 --------> 0
- -0.5 ------> 64 (equals 63.75 rounded)
- 0 ---------> 128 (equals 127.5 rounded)
- 0.5 -------> 191 (equals 191.25 rounded)
- 1-(1/128) -> 254 (equals 254.00390625 rounded)
- 0.999999 --> 255 (equals 254.9998725 rounded)
- 1 ---------> 255 (legal)

---

They both seem to offer disadvantages and advantages.

With the first method, there's no rounding needed, outputs are clean, and the results are consistent up to the final position. Unfortunately, 1 isn't an allowed input, and so (for example) sinusoidal inputs may be an issue. Either the user would have to make sure the input never equals one, or preferably, the function would simply make sure anything over position 255 is truncated back to 255.

With the second method, +1 IS an allowed input, so there's no worry about producing an illegal output of 256. Unfortunately, results seem a little ugly with simple inputs. They need to be rounded, and the jump from say 64 to 128 is not the same jump as from 128 to 191 (which is a difference of 63, instead of 64). This is despite the input having equal differences (-0.5 to 0, and 0 to 0.5 respectively).

I also noticed that with the first method, there's double the range for the first and final position, since 255 to 255.999 truncate down to 255, and 0 to 0.999 truncate down to zero. With the second method, only 0 to 0.499 truncate down to zero, and only 254.5 to 255 truncate up to 255. All other numbers allow a size 1.0 range to be 'chosen' (e.g: 42.5 to 43.499 round to 43), so it sorta makes sense that the first and last position of the byte should also allow a 'full' size 1.0 range to themselves too. On the other hand, if 255 is the actual number 255 on the number line, then an argument could also be made that only half the range is allotted for that byte.

So I'm just looking for some more insights and properties of both systems. Which is the PROPER way of doing this?

Answer (score 0):

Either multiply by 127 (and add 128) or multiply by 128 but saturate the product to the [-128, +127] range (IOW, handle +1.0 specially).

If there isn't any particular required treatment of the min/max values, you shouldn't bother too much about them. Your signal should rarely reach those values. And when it does, an error of about 1/128 at one of the ends isn't going to be significant. You're losing quite a bit of info/quality in reducing to 8 bits already across the entire range, not just at one of its ends.

Btw, there are non-linear schemes too. See e.g. [μ-law algorithm](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/%CE%9C-law_algorithm), which, btw, does something similar at large magnitudes, they're encoded more coarsely than small ones and it's OK in practice (that is, for speech).

Comment: Using your first formula: -1 * 127 + 128 = 1 which is not what we want. I would think -1 should transform to zero, not one, otherwise we waste one of the 256 positions. I gave only 8 bits in my post for simplicity, obviously I would have higher bits in the final product.

Comment: @DanW Choose which end you want to sacrifice or, perhaps, figure out what you really need. So far I can't see how the end points are important.

Comment: @DanW I'll tell you what... You could, for example, scale the negatives by 128 and the positives by 127. And you'd use all of the 256 values. The problem is, that sort of asymmetric processing would introduce an additional non-linear distortion across the entire range. I'd rather just sacrifice one of the values.

Comment: I guess I'm looking for mathematical perfection here, or as close as possible. Also, using your formula `n * 127 + 128`, I see it has the same problems that plague my "Method 2" - where some numbers are 63 apart and others are 64 apart. At least Method 2 doesn't waste either of the end points, so I can't see how  `n * 127 + 128` provides any advantage over either Method 1 or Method 2.

Comment: "scale the negatives by 128 and the positives by 127": Yes I'd never want to do that.

Comment: @DanW Then chose min or max to sacrifice. Either is rare and unimportant.

Comment: @DanW Not happy with the options/explanations listed here? Try a more relevant dsp.stackexchange.

Answer (score 0):

Method 1 is the start of a mathematically correct way to do the quantization.  You just need to add handling for the maximum value as a special case (the second suggestion in [Alexey's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/54551163/4078718) about saturating the product).  As you've noticed, this method provides equal size 'buckets', including the first and final ones.

The general solution involves two steps: normalizing the input values, followed by scaling.

Normalization of your -1 to 1 input values is simply:

j = (input + 1) / 2

which gets them into the range 0 to 1.  Scaling these values gives the final output value, where N is the number of quatization buckets:

output = Floor( N * j )

Floor() is equivalent to truncation.  You can prove to yourself that this is the "proper" way by imagining the simple case of N = 2.  Real values from 0 up to, but not including, 1 would fall into the 2 buckets fairly.  In the case of 8-bit quantization we have N = 256, and so:

**If input < 1, output = Floor( 128 * (input + 1) )**

or, your formula from method 1.

Handling the special case, when j = 1, we need to force the output value to be N - 1.  This may seem artificial, and it is.  But it's not going to cause any distortion; it's simply an arbitrary assignment in the special case of a point value on a line of real numbers.

**If input = 1, output = 255**

Having said all of that, the difference in the results of methods 1 and 2, resulting from the slight difference in the assignment of real values to the 256 levels, will be imperceptible.  As Alexey noted, a lot of information is being lost anyway in quantization to 8-bit values.